# Universal six-functor formalism on an $\infty$-category

Tags: higher-category-theory, motivic-homotopy, six-operations

In the article [The Universal Six-Functor Formalism](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.13610) by Brad Drew and Martin Gallauer it is proved that for an ordinary category $S$ with a wide subcategory $P$ of 'smooth morphisms' containing all isomorphisms and stable under pullbacks along morphisms in $S$, there is a universal 'pullback functor' $S^{\rm op} \to \operatorname{CAlg}(\operatorname{Cat}_{\infty})$ which can be described as assigning to $s$ the category $P_s$ of smooth morphisms $p: s' \to s$ with target $s$, with functoriality in $s$ given by taking pullbacks.

**Question:** Does the same hold if $S$ is an $\infty$-category?

It seems that the proof uses that $S$ is an ordinary category, but I don't understand it enough to tell whether the result breaks down if $S$ is an $\infty$-category. (My main interest is when $S$ is a presheaf $\infty$-category.)

**Added explanation**: a functor $C: S^{\rm op} \to \operatorname{CAlg}(\operatorname{Cat}_{\infty})$ is called a *pullback formalism* by Drew and Gallauer if it is $P$-left-adjointable, i.e.

1. for each morphism $p: s' \to s$ in $P$, the functor $p^* = C(p): C(s) \to C(s')$ has a left adjoint $p_{\sharp}$;
2. it satisfies *$P$-base change:* for each pullback square
   $\require{AMScd}$
   \begin{CD}
   t' @>{f'}>> s' \\
   @V{p'}VV @VV{p}V \\
   t @>{f}>> s
   \end{CD}
   with $p$ a morphism in $P$, the exchange transformation $p'_{\sharp}(f')^* \implies f^*p_\sharp$ is a natural equivalence;
3. it satisfies the *$P$-projection formula*: the exchange transformation
   \begin{aligned}
   p_\sharp(p^*(-) \otimes -) \implies - \otimes p_\sharp(-)
   \end{aligned}
   is an equivalence.

Comment: The authors posit in their introduction that this should usually be possible.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't seen that! Thanks